# Как сделать арифметическую прогрессию в C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

начал изучать C++ в универе, 1 курс, но это не важно. На лабе задали сделать арифметическую и геометрическую прогрессию и сложить суммы всех членов в той и в другой прогрессиях. Запретил использовать циклы и проверку условия if. Код целиком скидывать не прошу, просто натолкните на путь истинный, пожалуйста. Но от кода тоже не откажусь, постараюсь разобраться. Всем мир.

Comment: может через while ? да, это цикл, но кто знает, что они имели ввиду? не представляю, как первокурссники спустя 16 дней без циклов это сделают.

Comment: что означает "сделать прогрессию"? А сумма членов в той и другой считается по формуле без всяких циклов.

Comment: Препод сказал, что значения можешь выбирать другие, допустим 2 до 48 с шагом  2, нужно чтобы переменная изменялась от 2 до 48 и складывала все значения изменяющейся переменной. 2+4+6+8...

Comment: [Алгебра 9 класс](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/algebra/9-klass/chislovye-posledovatelnosti-progressii-9139/geometricheskaia-progressiia-svoistva-geometricheskoi-progressii-9142/re-1cea80c1-2bde-4270-a473-6b6d81ad228d)

Comment: это означает, что нужно просто посчитать сумму, а "сделать прогрессию" не надо

Comment: Какое-то ну очень странное условие, если только от вас не хотят что-то вроде `sum = 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+2) + (1+2+2+2);`...

Comment: Если без циклов, то можно через рекурсию. Но если еще и без ```if````.....

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов ... тогда использовать switch

Comment: @Аркадий Можно конечно. Вопрос только в том, чего хотел преподаватель. Поскольку ```switch``` ничем принципиально не отличается то ```if```

Comment: ребят, есть же формулы для нахождения арифметической прогресссии, ее членов и всей суммы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить три варианта. На примере арифметической прогрессии. В Вашей формулировке не совсем ясно, что имел в виду преподаватель (а может, это он так поставил задачу), так что мы практически пальцем в небо тыкаем.

Самый очевидный и простой вариант, который предложил господин MBo из комментариев - воспользоваться формулой арифметической прогрессии.

```
int main( )
{
    int first  = 1;     // первый член прогрессии
    int step   = 1;     // разность прогрессии
    int number = 10;    // количество суммируемых членов
    
    int result = (2 * first + step * (number - 1)) * number / 2;
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Вариант второй - использовать рекурсию вместо цикла и тернарный оператор ?: вместо if (switch)

```
int arithmetic(int steps, int previous, int add)
{
    steps
    ? previous += arithmetic(steps - 1, previous + add, add)
    : previous
    ;
    
    return previous;        
}

int main( )
{       
    int first  = 1;
    int step   = 1;
    int number = 10;

    int result = arithmetic(number - 1, first, step);  
    cout << result << endl;     
}
```

Вариант третий - совсем без условных переходов (даже в виде хитрого тернарного оператора) - рекурсия с использованием шаблонов. Навряд ли это на первом курсе дают - разделяю мнение господина Wlad в комментариях.

Но раз мы не знаем точного задания, то просто Вам на будущее и для любопытства. Ну и может просто еще кому-то понадобится.

```
template<int steps>
int arithmetic(int previous, int add)
{   
    previous += arithmetic<steps - 1>(previous + add, add);
    return previous;
}

template< >
int arithmetic<0>(int previous, int add )
{
    return previous;
}   

int main( )
{
    int first  = 1;
    int step   = 1;
    int number = 10;

    int result = arithmetic<number - 1>(first, step);
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: Третий вариант красиво. Рекурсия на шаблонах....